# Ruby on rails: Model Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm newer to rails and not sure how to go about this. I have the standard model named User and in User I have 10 different attributes. The 10 attributes include the attribute for the user to choose weather he is type "a" or type "b". When a user clicks on signup I want them to choose weather they are type "a" or type "b". If they are type "a" I want them to be redirected to fill out only 5 of the attributes. If they are type "b" I want them to fill out the other 4 attributes. My question is how do I create the logic in the controller to where it redirects me to the correct form after the first initial question.

[Edited]

Would This be logical?

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def new
    @user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.new(personality_selection)

    if @user.save
       redirect_to root_path
    else 
       render :new
    end
end

private
def personality_selection
    params.require(:user).permit(:personality_a_or_b)

    if params[:personality] == 'a'
       redirect_to type_a_path
    elsif params[:personality] == 'b'
       redirect_to type_b_path
    end
end

def type_a
    params.require(:user).permit(:trait2, :trait3, :trait4 :trait5, :trait6)
end

def type_b
    params.requrie(:user).permit(:trait7, :trait8, :trait9, :trait10)
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have an initial form where the User enters the non-personality information and whether they are type 'a' or 'b'. The selection of type 'a' or 'b' should entered into attribute 'personality_type'.

On saving, the controller will redirect to a new personality-specific form with only fields that pertain to that personality.

On saving the next form, it will save to the Update controller action and just update the personality fields.

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      if @user.personality_type == 'a'     
        redirect_to edit_personality_a_path(@user)
      else
        redirect_to edit_personality_b_path(@user)
      end
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id]
    @user.update(user_params)
    redirect_to @user
  end

  def edit_personality_a
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit_personality_b
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(..params..)
  end
end
```

**edit_personality_a.html.erb**

```
= form_for @user do |f|
 .... put all the form fields that are specific 'a' personality.
```

**edit_personality_b.html.erb**

```
= form_for @user do |f|
 .... put all the form fields that are specific 'b' personality.
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :users do
  get 'edit-personality-a' => 'users#edit_personality_a', as: 'edit_personality_a'
  get 'edit-personality-b' => 'users#edit_personality_b', as: 'edit_personality_b'
end
```

Comment: I know this is not correct and it's just an example, but would it look like this?

Comment: I revised my answer to be more specific. Lots of ways to do this. You could also combine the two personality forms into one and then conditionally show the fields you want.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I'm learning rails at a decent pace, but theres always things like this that stump me.  Thank you again for the detailed response.

Comment: @G.Gary I added additional material and refinements so hopefully the direction is more clear on how you can approach it.  Keeping all the attributes in the User model is simple, which makes having multiple forms using the same controller update action a great idea.